# Applescript to change Sound output intermittently

Tags: applescript, audio

I am trying to have an applescript run every 2 minutes that would open sound preferences, then change the audio output by pressing the up key, followed by the down key.  I am using a TV for external audio and it is creating some static but if I change the audio output to a different source and then back again, the static is gone for a random period of time.  I am not a Mac user and have never created an applescript before.  Searching around, this is the closest I can get but still gives me an error when I try to compile.  I am on Mohave.

```
tell application "System Events"
  delay 0.5
  keystroke space using command down
  delay 0.5
  keystroke "Sound"
  delay 0.5
  keystroke return
  delay 1
  keycode "125"
  delay 1
  keycode "126
end tell
```